# I need to create a Table from two unrelated old tables in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

My problem is that I need to create the table USER_LIBRARY from this two unrelated tables:

```
USER:
    ID_USER NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(50),
    SURNAME VARCHAR2(50),
    CITY VARCHAR2(50),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
    AGE NUMBER(9),
    EMAIL VARCHAR2(50)

LIBRARY:
        id_library number(9) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
        city VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
        address VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
        CP number(9) NOT NULL
```

I try with an INNER JOIN and with UNION but it doesn´t work, I'm new to Oracle so I know is a basic question but I didn´t know how to solve.

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: the user-library table has to contain the fields of the user and library tables

Answer (score 0):

If you want all users to pair with all libraries, you could use:

```
create table user_library as
    select u.id_user, l.id_library
    from user u cross join
         library l;
```

This includes only the ids.  You can use `JOIN` to fetch the values corresponding to a particular user and/or library.

Answer (score 0):

The final table will depend on how many columns of both input tables you want to use. As you have columns with the same name, you need to use alias to resolve this in a good way. Another thing is what result you expect. Normally a user may belong to one or more libraries, but as you have no way to relate both tables, you will get a cartesian product.

Let's assume you want all of them

```
create table user_library as
select u.id_user , 
       l.id_library, 
       u.name as user_name, 
       u.surname , 
       u.city as user_city , 
       u.address as user_address, 
       u.age, u.email , 
       l.name as library_name, 
       l.city as library_city, 
       l.address as library_address ,
       l.cp as library_cp 
 from user u cross join library l ;
```

Let me explain what I mean with an example

```
SQL> create table test1 ( c1 number , c2 number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test1 values ( 1 , 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test1 values ( 2 , 2 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> create table test2 ( c3 number, c4 number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test2 values ( 3 , 3 );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test2 values ( 4 , 4 );

1 row created.

SQL> create table test3 as select a.c1 , a.c2 , b.c3 , b.c4 from test1 a cross join test2 b ;

Table created.

SQL> select * from test1 ;

        C1         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          2

SQL> select * from test2 ;

        C3         C4
---------- ----------
         3          3
         4          4

SQL> select * from test3 ;

        C1         C2         C3         C4
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          3          3
         1          1          4          4
         2          2          3          3
         2          2          4          4

SQL>
```

The cross join creates a row for each combination of values in table1 against table2.